# Is there any way to make a method check if there is existing unique data in database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, runtime-error

My goal is to create a method in android studio that checks if there is an existing username (which is unique) in my database. But my problem is, I have no idea why my implemented code does not work and returns an error in logcat. The app does not crash however.

In fact, I have tried implementing 2 different methods. The first one is to put all selected existing usernames from the database into an arraylist and use the ArrayList.contains(username) method to see if the arraylist contains the similar username.

The other method I have tried using is to select a username in the database that is the same as my inputted username and see if they are the same. (Might sound confusing but I will show you the code).

MainActivity.java

```
DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this, "MyUsers", null, 1);

UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(tvUsername.getText().toString(), etEnterPassword.getText().toString());

            if (mydb.existingUsername(tvUsername.getText().toString()) == false) {
                mydb.insertTable(userInfo);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lobby.class);
                intent.putExtra("username", userInfo.getUsername());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // some code
            }
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " text not null unique, " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " text)");
}

// Method 1 (Commented out)
public ArrayList<UserInfo> existingUsername() {
    UserInfo userInfo;
    ArrayList<UserInfo> userArray = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        userInfo = new UserInfo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)));
        userArray.add(userInfo);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return userArray;
}

// Method 2 (Currently in use)
public boolean existingUsername(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[]{username});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)) == username) {
            return true;
        } else {
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Expected results:

I want it to check if the "username" I put already exists in the database or not. If no, run the "if" statement and go to the next activity. If yes, run the "else" statement.

Actual results:

However, it turns out the code keeps running the "if" statement and goes the next activity whether the inputted username already exists in the database or not. If the inputted username already exists in the database, it gives me this error in the logcat.

Logcat

```
019-06-01 14:06:19.774 27199-27199/com.karimun.myapplication E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting password=232323 username=Igor
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
    at com.karimun.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.insertTable(DatabaseHelper.java:70)
    at com.karimun.myapplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong comparison

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)) == username
```

This cause your program continue inserting even when the username already exists.

Change to `equals()` for correct string comparison. Do not use `==` to compare String (and objects generally)

```
username.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)))
```

if `username` is not null

or

```
Objects.equals(username, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should let SQL do all of the work for you:

```
Select count(*) from sometable where username = @username
```

This will return the number of records that contain @username. If the number is 0, then the username does not exist in the table. If it's 1, then the username exists and is unique. If it's greater than 1, then the username exists and is not unique.

Comment: MikeT answer means not need to check with more SQL one SQL do all one go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your **`insertTable(userInfo)`** method but if you use (assuming you are using the execSQL method to insert) then using `INSERT OR IGNORE` instead of `INSERT` then the duplicate will be ignored.

However, if instead you use the [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues)) method (this effectively uses INSERT OR IGNORE). It returns the **rowid**, as a long, of the inserted row, if the row wasn't inserted then it returns -1. So checking the return value will tell you that for some reason (likely a duplicate) that the row wasn't inserted (so negates the need for a pre-check and the associated overheads).

- As you have defined the ID columns using `integer primary key autoincrement`, this column is an alias of the **rowid** column (so the value of rowid will be the same as the ID column).

The following is the code as it could perhaps be, based upon what can be gleaned from the available code.

```
public long insertTable(UserInfo userInfo) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    SQliteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,userInfo.getUserName());
    cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,userInfo.getPassword());
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
}
```

- Note as this has the same name and signature this would have to replace your existing method or be named differently.
- Note **getPassword** may be the wrong method used to get the password value from the UserInfo

The code in MainActivity.java could then be :-

```
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(tvUsername.getText().toString(), etEnterPassword.getText().toString());

        long id;
        if (id = mydb.insertTable(userInfo) > 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lobby.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", userInfo.getUsername());
            intent.putExtra("userid",id); //<<<<<<<<<< you now have the id
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // some code because user was not added
        }
```

- Note the above is in-principle code and may contain some errors as it hasn;t been tested or run.

Comment: This better way, less not needed access as it all one go, less memory use as no get Cursor and as well less code.

Comment: Hey MikeT, I tried your code. The "insertTable" works. But the problem is if I use "if (mydb.insertTable(userInfo) > 0)", it returns the same error as mentioned above. But it does prevent me from going to another activity.

Comment: @Samaritan the error is trapped and the stack-race printed but it doesn't raise an exception (it's the way that the API has been written).